# Items not adding to list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have custom class `Map` which contains 2 lists of custom classes `Bricks` and `Dangers`. Problem is that my code is not adding elements to that custom classes.

```
public class Map
{
    public string mapName;
    public List<Brick> bricks;
    public List<Danger> dangers;

    public Map()
    {
        bricks = new List<Brick>();
        dangers = new List<Danger>();
    }
}

public class Brick
{
    public Vector2 Position;
}

public class Danger
{
    public Vector2 Position;
}
private void CreateMap()
{
    Map map = new Map();
    map.mapName = "test";

    map.bricks.Add(new Brick { Position = new Vector2(1, 1) });
    map.bricks.Add(new Brick { Position = new Vector2(2, 1) });
    map.bricks.Add(new Brick { Position = new Vector2(5, 1) });
    map.bricks.Add(new Brick { Position = new Vector2(6, 1) });
    map.bricks.Add(new Brick { Position = new Vector2(7, 1) });

    map.dangers.Add(new Danger { Position = new Vector2(3, 1) });
    map.dangers.Add(new Danger { Position = new Vector2(4, 1) });

    Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(map));
    AddMap(map);
}
```

As an output from `Debug.Log` i get `{"mapName:": "test"}`

Comment: I think this has to do with JsonUtility. Set a breakpoint on the AddMap line and view if map.blicks is indeed empty.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34274465/2189031

Comment: Code runs fine in VS 2015. See above comment

Comment: Yea. I started coding few months ago and made about 15 days break so i am still making stupid mistakes. Forgot to `SerializeField`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is for type of serializing object.
Add [Serializable] attribute to your classes and try again. I think you must add it to Vector properties too.